# How can i export maven dependecies in a zip created from Ant?

Tags: maven, ant

I have a project where the dependencies are maged by maven and i use ant to properties values injection ant to export the project as zip. i would like to include my maven dependencies in the zip created by ant. Is it possibile? Thank you

Comment: What not using Maven for all things... creating a zip can be done via maven-assembly-plugin ... ?

Comment: Because i use Ant for properties defining

Comment: That makes no sense cause you are using Maven for dependencies? ... Make everything with Maven and it's easier... Ant for properties defining? What kind of properties and where do you use them etc. ? Missing information ... I strongly recommend to get rid of Ant and do all with Maven...